# I dont seem to understand the basic difference between factory method and abstract factory method.. Explanation with scenario of apple products

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I went through few of previous question too about the difference between abstract factory and factory method. Suppose, I have apple factory, which produces  3 different apple products, iphone, ipod, and ipad. The specs of these 3 product are different as well.. but there may be some similarities though. which design pattern should be used.

any Help appreciated. Thankyou

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have one factory function that returns some kind of `AppleProduct*` to an instance of `IPhone`, `IPod` or `IPad`, that would constitute a factory method pattern.

If you wanted distinct factory functions for say "retina" class display devices and non-retina devices, your program might first choose a concrete factory method from the retina- and non-retina factories, then access that concrete factory from an abstract factory interface.  This effectively gives you some modality over the factory, so you're using it the same way for retina or non-retina products, but can make the decision of which set of products to deal with once.  Such modality is a much rarer requirement than the simpler direct use of a factory method pattern as above.

Answer (score 0):

this 2 patterns aren't incompatible in fact. Factory pattern indicates the caller havn't to know the implementation (just the interface) of an object. Abstract Factory pattern indicates that if the desired object follows a hierarchy, the factories follow a "similar" hierarchy

So in your example, you can apply the Abstract Factory pattern. You have an AbstractAppleProduct class with 3 subclasses and an AbstractAppleProductFactory with 3 others subclasses too.